# Copy paste a table from a webpage to Gmail

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gmail

**Edit**: my original question was about IPython notebook (Jupyter), although I found that the same behaviour is with arbitrary tables from the web.

I would like to be able to copy (Ctrl+C) and paste (Ctrl+V) tables (and potentially images) with their formatting from web pages to Gmail. I am using Ubuntu and Firefox.

It appears to work when I simply select, copy and paste a table - it gets displayed in my gmail draft with the right formatting. Unfortunately when I click send, the table gets converted into a hardly readable raw text.

There are ways around it. I can select slightly more than just the table, then copy+paste+send works fine. Or I can select just the table, copy-paste it to LibreOffice and then copy-paste it to Gmail.

Could someone explain how this is supposed to work internally and in which component (Firefox, Ubuntu, Gmail or Javascript) the problem lies here?